# jQuery focusOut except if

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I simply want to hide a div, if a text box loses focus, unless, the user clicks in another certain div. If user clicks that particular div, then the focusout doesn't trigger the div.box being hidden.

Below is code with my pseudocode commenting. Any ideas?

```
textInput.focusout(function() {
    // So long you didn't click div.stop, then
        $('div.box').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var flag = false;

$('div.stop').click(function() {flag = true;});
textInput.focusout(function() {
    // So long you didn't click div.stop, then
    if(!flag)
        $('div.box').hide();
});
```

If you wanted to avoid adding the flag variable, you could use jQuery's [.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store the flag value against e.g. the `div.stop` element, e.g:

```
$('div.stop').click(function() {$(this).data('clicked', true);});

// ...

    if(!$('div.stop').data('clicked'))
// ...
```

**EDIT**

If you want to allow for the situation where the text box has focus, and you then click on `div.stop`, and you don't want it to hide, then you could try something like:

```
$('div.stop').click(function() {$('div.box').stop();});
textInput.focusout(function() {
    // So long you didn't click div.stop, then
    $('div.box').delay(200).hide();
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... have you tested it? I think that the text box might lose focus before `click` fires on the button.

Comment: I did some modifications to enable it to be fired multiple times in a document, but the general solution you provided was correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).bind('click',function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('div.box').length) return;
  $('div.box').hide();
});
```

Try this!

Answer (score 2):

```
var flag = false;
$('#inputID').blur(function(){
   $('div.box').toggle(flag);       
});

$('#someDIVid').click(function(){
    flag = true;
});
```

## [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mYmeq/)

added notes:

> **.toggle( showOrHide )**
>
> **showOrHide** A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements. If this parameter is `true`, then the matched *elements are shown*; if `false`, the *elements are hidden*.

Comment: There's no point in using toggle here - `if(!flag) ....hide()` is more efficient and easier to read.

Comment: @sje397 - I expected someone would say that :) But you were the one to answer first, so I have to think of other ways. What's in my mind is maybe the OP may want to show the box again after clicking another box (`div.stop` on OP) if `div.box` already hidden. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by setting timer on `focusout`:

```
$(document).on("focusout", "#textInput", function () 
{
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $('div.box').hide();
    }, 101); //I've added 101ms to wait before hiding. (Lower than 80 often fails on my pc)
});
```